# Super-simple before insert trigger (2 rows) does not work when inserting values into a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building a trigger which raises an application error if the length of a string is not 16.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER lunghezza_CF
before INSERT OR UPDATE ON Persona
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(:NEW.CF) <> 16 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'CF length must be 16');
    END IF;
END;
```

The table `Persona` is composed as follows:

```
CF char(16) primary key
...
```

If i write the following statement

```
insert into Persona(CF) values('ABC12')
```

For what reason 'ABC12' gets inserted into the table? For some reason my trigger does not work properly, but it seems to be ok...

(Note that LENGTH(string) is an Oracle "built-in" function)

Comment: What's your question..? Are you able to insert that value ?

Comment: 'ABC12' should not be inserted due to the trigger. But 'ABC12' is inserted

Comment: You should avoid `CHAR` entirely. The standard string type in Oracle is `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: I used to declare a `char` for those variables whose length is pre-fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `char` data type which is blank padded to the length defined and therefore always exactly as long as its definition. You can use `trim()` to remove blanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER lunghezza_CF
before INSERT OR UPDATE ON Persona
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(TRIM(:NEW.CF)) <> 16 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'CF length must be 16');
    END IF;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea97261ab9af3382c04481c6bb034fcf)

But instead of a trigger, you could also simply use a check constraint for this.

```
ALTER TABLE persona
            ADD CHECK (length(trim(cf)) = 16);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=087e37aa88ca2b9992ddac87a47098a6)

Note, that `trim()` removes trailing and leading blanks. If you want to count leading blanks you can use `rtrim()` instead, which just removes trailing blanks.